# How is English Premier League order position determined if teams are tied?

Tags: rules, football, english-premier-league

[image: EPL league table]

If two teams in the Premier League are tied on goal difference, goals against, have scored and conceded the same number of goals, how is the order of their position determined?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, other questions ask about tiebreaker at the end of season, I'm asking  if the teams have not played each and there is no head to head and they are tied, while the season is on going,how is the order generated?

Comment: Because the most correct duplicate of your question is this one: [Tiebreakers to decide league position in football (soccer)?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/tiebreakers-to-decide-league-position-in-football-soccer). I.e the question to which this question is referenced as a duplicate is itself a duplicate of aforementioned question.

Comment: So the answer to your question is: **they occupy the same position in the table**, which is contained in the mentioned link.

Comment: true they occupy the position but as you can see from the image, it looks like the final order is done alphabetically.I just wanted if this was correct.apologies for any confusion caused

Comment: You're right, even [official site of the tournament](https://www.premierleague.com/tables) shows City as first, but definitely for alphabetical reasons as you've already mentioned.